# Telerik RadWindow and standard CSS Conflicts (in Internet Explorer)

Tags: asp.net, css, telerik, rad-controls, radwindow

I am doing a project in ASP.NET/C# using Telerik RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX and have put in a lot of effort in designing the site. Now all of a sudden RadWindow threatens all the CSS Styles in place. This is a really peculiar problem and it is only with Internet Explorer. Someone please help me correcting this..

Almost 100% of the content in my site use CSS(not CSS3). Everything was looking and working good(in all browsers incl. IE), until I added a Telerik RadWindow into the page.
After this IE is not rendering my CSS Styles and my site looks like a complete CRAP!!
But the other browsers like chrome and firefox are working flawlessly. Even the addition of RadWindowManager alone without any actual RadWindows causes the same trouble.

Note: CSS of RadControls looks good & DOES NOT HAVE any trouble. This is only with the other standard HTML/ASP.NET elements/controls.

I am using Masterpage and if I move the RadWindow/Manager to the MasterPage, it then filters down the bug to all child/content pages i.e all child pages are not applying the CSS Styling. But the CSS Styles in my MasterPage is Okay. I am completely puzzled by this behavior and couldnt find what is wrong.

I also checked the CSS used by RadWindow and there was NO class/classname that conflicts with any of the classes I am using with the elements in the content pages. All the above mentioned probs ARE ONLY WITH INTERNET EXPLORER. :(

Have anyone ecountered this kind of issue ? Kindly help me since I am in dire need of RadWindow and couldn't eliminate it from my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if you are not hitting the 30 stylesheets on a page limit in IE. If you have a lot of stylesheet registrations, IE will not parse them all and you will have missing styles. Other browsers are unaffected by this limitation. Try combining your CSS into one or if you are using more than one of the RadControls, add a RadStyleSheetManager to your master page.

Comment: Man you are a genius.. It was certainly the 31 stylesheets limitation with this crappy IE that caused the trouble. Which is an even worse news for me. Can I merge my stylesheets? Or do we have a "no of lines" limitation as well ? And yes, I am having multiple RadControls in my pages. I'll sure Add a stylesheet manager. I am using Clear skin by Telerik(which I guess is considered as a CustomSkin). So should I be follwing (http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/radstylesheetmanager.html) these steps for each Control ? Please guide me.. Thanks a million buddy..

Comment: Ps: Since I am using Clear Skin(custom), I am having to add a link to the .CSS files for each of the RadControls. Which is certainly gonna bite my "no of stylesheets" allowed preventing me from adding any more custom sheets for standard HTML/ASP.NET Controls.          So does addition of RadStyleSheetManager makes the browser consider the Clear skin's .css files as ONE ?

Comment: RadStyleSheetManager will only help if you are using the built-in skins. If you are loading the .css files for your skin manually, then you should combine them into one big .css file and load it instead of the separate files. For example, if you have ClearSkin/Window.css and ClearSkin/Grid.css and ClearSkin/Menu.css, you can combine them all into one file ClearSkin/CombinedWindowGridMenu.css. Make sure that you only combine files from the same folder so you don't break the links inside them.

Comment: Thanks a lot lingvomir. I have merged my Telerik Custom Skin's CSS into one and linked it from my Masterpage. Now everything works fine... You are a lifesaver!!!! :) CHEERS!!